# output from GDAL ogr2ogr

Tags: php, gdal, ogr2ogr

I want to convert a .shp file to .geojson format using ogr2ogr, which I can do from the (linux) command line. 
However, rather than a command line conversion, I want to invoke the conversion from a php script (using e.g. exec(..) ) and send the output directly to a variable (as a character string) instead of writing to a file.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell_exec() method available in PHP.

```
public function shptogeojson($shpfilepath,$output,$srsno,$srsold){
 $query="ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:$srsno -s_srs EPSG:$srsold $output.shp $shpfilepath";
 shell_exec($query);
 }
```